# How to capture two inputDate() and calculate number of days in shinyapp?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to capture two different 'dateInput()' and calculate number of days in shinyApp.
Can someone help me on this, please?

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Leave"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(4, dateInput('st', "Start Date", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", width = '200px')),
    column(4, dateInput('ed',"End Date", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", width = '200px')),
    column(4, valueBoxOutput('caldif'))
    )
              
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  output$caldif <-  renderValueBox("Days",input$st - input$ed)
})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with the call of `renderValueBox`. It requires a `valueBox()` inside it. `difftime` is probably the best function to calculate time differences.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Leave"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(4, dateInput('st', "Start Date", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", width = '200px')),
    column(4, dateInput('ed',"End Date", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", width = '200px')),
    column(4, valueBoxOutput('caldif', width = 8))
  )
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  output$caldif <-  renderValueBox({  
      #valueBox needed here
      #difftime will calculate the time difference
      valueBox('Days', as.character(difftime(input$ed, input$st)))
    })
})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Output:

[image]